# Mobile Connect Filtered List Includes Opt-Outs?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

I am creating a filtered list in Mobile Connect contact builder, and there doesn't seem to be a way to filter by opt-in status (I assume because it's pulling from all contacts) . With that in mind, the filtered list I create ends up including people who aren't actively opted-in.

My question is: will SFMC Mobile Connect exclude anybody in that list who isn't opted-in at the time of send, or will it force a send to all contacts in the list (even if they aren't opted-in)?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a filtered list of opt-ins.

Navigate to:
Contact Builder > All Contacts > Mobile Lists > Create Mobile List >

- Channel = Mobile Connect
- Method = Filtered List
- Population = {Your Keyword}

This will then open up the Data Designer and your Attribute Groups.

On the left panel, navigate through your data model:
MobileConnect Data > MobileConnect Demographics > MobileConnect Subscriptions

The drag the Opt In Status Field and choose Opted In.

[image]